# Yii2 - Pass ID to another attribute in GridView

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, gridview, yii

I want to pass the `ID` to another column that using Javascript.
Here is my code:

```
['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'alumni_id', /*I want to pass this value*/
        'tahun_lulus',
        'file_excel',
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function($data){
                return SwitchInput::widget(
                  [
                      'name' => 'status_11',
                      'pluginEvents' => [
                          'switchChange.bootstrapSwitch' => 'function() { 
                                $.ajax({
                                  method: "POST",
                                  url: "'.Url::to(['/alumni/switch', 'id'=>'1']).'",
                                  data: { status_11: this.checked }
                              })
                            }',
                      ],
                      'pluginOptions' => [
                          'size' => 'mini',
                          'onColor' => 'success',
                          'offColor' => 'danger',
                          'onText' => 'Active',
                          'offText' => 'Inactive',
                      ],
                      'value' => !$data->status
                  ]
                );
            }
        ],
```

I want to pass the attribute `alumni_id` to the attribute `status` that has a Javascript there (to this `Url::to(['/alumni/switch', 'id'=>'1']`).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by the following  code:

```
$data->alumni_id
```

If you want to pass `id` value as `$data->alumni_id` then:

```
Url::to(['/alumni/switch', 'id'=>$data->alumni_id])
```

Comment: Yeah finally. Thank you